# Control search box location RenderDataTable R

Tags: shiny, dt

How can I control the position of the search box in the RenderDataTable function in shiny?

```
DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(org3, rownames = F, escape = F,
      options=list(sDom  = '<"top">lrt<"bottom">ip')....
```

The sDom doesn't seem to do anything except make the box disappear.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether `sDom` works, I always use `dom`. The search box is coded by `f` in the `dom` option ("f" for "filter").

```
DT::datatable(iris, rownames = FALSE, escape = FALSE,
              options=list(dom = '<"top">lfrt<"bottom">ip'))
```